# Add another sliding drawer on the right side fail

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I wanted to add sliding drawer next to another sliding drawer, currently my output is:

[image]

Arrow # 1 should be my first sliding drawer

Arrow # 2 is where my second sliding drawer should be

I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/asof"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"
        android:content="@+id/right_content_a"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:handle="@+id/right_handle"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right_handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/tab"
            android:text="" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_content_a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:tag="eacomm" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/field_ex"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"
        android:content="@+id/right_content_a"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:handle="@+id/right_handle2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_handle2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/tab" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_content_a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:tag="eacomm2" >
        </FrameLayout>

    </SlidingDrawer>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas? TIA!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it by creating two sliding drawer XML files and binding it to the main container/layout. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Slider drawer will capture complete row of the layout. So you will not be able to put another slider drawer or any other view that needs to capture the tap or focus.